# Back button behaviour on activity to fragment in bottom navigation view

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, fragment-backstack

I have a `bottomnavigationview` containing 5 fragments,(Consider A(Home), B, C, D, E) If I go to fragment D and then an Activity (Which is inside fragment D or C or any of 5) and press back button of the device. It is directly going to Home fragment(A), actually, it should go to fragment D or C.
I have used `botomnavigationview` in my previous project but all things were working fine.

**Happening-- MainActivity+HomeFragment (A)---> Fragment D-->>Activity--->>OnbackPressed--->>HomeFragment**

**Expected-- MainActivity+HomeFragment (A)---> Fragment D-->>Activity--->>OnbackPressed--->>D fragment**

any help is appreciated.

**Fragment D CODE IS LIKE THIS**

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {

public Button button;
private String TAG = AccountFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private TextView mContactustextView, mAddress, rateUs, aboutus, tvOrderHistory, userPhone, userEmail, buyerUserName, faqs;

public static AccountFragment newInstance() {

    AccountFragment fragment = new AccountFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    Utils.matchColorOfStatusBar(getActivity());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.accountfragment, container, false);
    button = view.findViewById(R.id.login_button_account_page);
    userPhone = view.findViewById(R.id.userPhone);
    buyerUserName = view.findViewById(R.id.buyerUserName);
    userEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.userEmail);
    aboutus = view.findViewById(R.id.aboutus);
    tvOrderHistory = view.findViewById(R.id.tvOrderHistory);
    faqs = view.findViewById(R.id.faqs);

    faqs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FAqsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

        }
    });

    aboutus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AboutUsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    //Manage session here
    if (App.getInstance().getPrefManager().isLoggedIn()) {
        button.setText("Logout");
        Log.e(TAG, "isWorking");

    } else {
        button.setText("Login");
        userPhone.setText("");
        userEmail.setText("");
        buyerUserName.setText("");
        Log.e(TAG, "isNotWorking");

    }
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (App.getInstance().getPrefManager().isLoggedIn()) {
                App.getInstance().getPrefManager().setLoginSession(false);
                App.getInstance().getPrefManager().setCartCount(0);
                App.getInstance().getPrefManager().setFavCount(0);
                badgeCart();
                badgeFav();
                button.setText("Login");
                userPhone.setText("");
                userEmail.setText("");
                buyerUserName.setText("");
                Log.e(TAG, "ToLoginPage");
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

                Log.e(TAG, "log");
            }
        }
    });
    //findview by id
    rateUs = view.findViewById(R.id.rateus);
    mAddress = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
    mContactustextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_contact_us);
    rateUs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.test.android"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    mAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (App.getInstance().getPrefManager().isLoggedIn()) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AddressActivity.class).putExtra("source", AccountFragment.class.getSimpleName()));
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

            } else {

                Utils.showAlert(getContext(), getString(R.string.please_login));
            }
        }
    });
    tvOrderHistory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (App.getInstance().getPrefManager().isLoggedIn()) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MyOrdersListActivity.class));
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
            } else {

                Utils.showAlert(getContext(), getString(R.string.please_login));
            }
        }
    });
```

**Activity code is like this**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Utils.matchColorOfStatusBar(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_us);

    //FindViewByIds
    contact_via_call = findViewById(R.id.ll_call_custmr_care);
    rootLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.ll_contact_us);
    contact_via_email = findViewById(R.id.ll_email_custmr_care);
    ll_whatsapp = findViewById(R.id.ll_whatsapp);
    contact_via_email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject will be here");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{getString(R.string.supportemail)});

            try {
                ContactUsActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Utils.showSnakbarTypeOne(rootLinearLayout, "No email client installed");
                //showAlertMessage(context, "There are no email clients installed.");
            }
        }
    });

    ll_whatsapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            openWhatsApp();

        }
    });

    contact_via_call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String phone = getString(R.string.custmersupportnum);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    //setuptoolbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_contact_us);
    toolbar.setTitle("Contact Us");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}

}
```

**Main Activity is like this**

```
      private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home:

                    fragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
                    break;
                case R.id.favorite:
                    if (App.getInstance().getPrefManager().isLoggedIn())
                        fragment = FavoriteFragment.newInstance();
                    else {
                        Utils.showAlert(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.please_login));
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.categories:

                    fragment = CategoriesFragment.newInstance();
                    break;
                case R.id.carts:
                    if (App.getInstance().getPrefManager().isLoggedIn())
                        fragment = CartFragment.newInstance();
                    else {
                        Utils.showAlert(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.please_login));
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.accounts:

                    fragment = AccountFragment.newInstance();
                    break;
            }
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
            transaction.replace(R.id.home_container, fragment);
            transaction.commit();

            return true;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
private void cartBadgeCount(){
    BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(mBottomNavigationView);
    BottomNavigationMenuView bottomNavigationMenuView =
            (BottomNavigationMenuView) mBottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
    View v = bottomNavigationMenuView.getChildAt(2);
    BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) v;
    View badge = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            .inflate(R.layout.notification_badge, bottomNavigationMenuView, false);
    tvCartCount = badge.findViewById(R.id.notification_badge);
    itemView.addView(badge);

    mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);
    if (Validation.isValidString(getIntent().getStringExtra(Constant.GO_TO_CART)) && getIntent().getStringExtra(Constant.GO_TO_CART).equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.GO_TO_CART)) {
//            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.home_container, new CartFragment()).commit();
//            bottomNavigationMenuView.getSelectedItemId().setSelected(true);
        View view = bottomNavigationMenuView.findViewById(R.id.carts);
        view.performClick();
    }

}
    private void favCountBadge() {
        BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(mBottomNavigationView);
        BottomNavigationMenuView bottomNavigationMenuView =
                (BottomNavigationMenuView) mBottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);

        View v = bottomNavigationMenuView.getChildAt(3);
        BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) v;
        View badge = LayoutInflater.from(this)
                .inflate(R.layout.notification_badge, bottomNavigationMenuView, false);
        tvFav = badge.findViewById(R.id.notification_badge);
        itemView.addView(badge);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        cartBadgeCount();
        favCountBadge();

        if (App.getInstance().getPrefManager().getCartCount() > 0) {
            tvCartCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvCartCount.setText(String.valueOf(App.getInstance().getPrefManager().getCartCount()));
        } else
            tvCartCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (App.getInstance().getPrefManager().getFavCount() > 0) {
            tvFav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvFav.setText(String.valueOf(App.getInstance().getPrefManager().getFavCount()));
        } else
            tvFav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.e(TAG, "cart count " + 
      String.valueOf(App.getInstance().getPrefManager().getCartCount()));
        Log.e(TAG, "fav count " + 
    String.valueOf(App.getInstance().getPrefManager().getFavCount()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Confirmation")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to Exit?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new 
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {
                        finishAffinity();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
        }`enter code here`
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: the code is shared @YoLo

Comment: where is your main activity from where you are calling accountfragment

Comment: wait a minute .

Comment: main activity is updated @YoLo

Comment: its common behaviour when you go from one activity to another it takes the first activity in the stack but when you come back to the first activity the onResume method of the first activity is called! and it refreshes the BottomNavigationTabs! so my tip would be just code on resume with a flag that if the intent calling the activity is from 2nd activity then get the desired tab selected and also load desired fragment in the container! want code?

Comment: yes...would be helpful. Thank you so much @Rizwanatta

Comment: wel the answer of yolo is helpful! help me understand here a little that ! your problem is when you come back from another activity you get the first activity's FirstFragment opened! right? and you want the fragment which opened the 2ndActivity intact while returning to it!

Comment: absolutely correct @Rizwanatta

Comment: n my previous application, all things are working fine but not in current one. Now its so frustrating for me

Comment: bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true); 

this will help you to get the tab selected! in bottom navigation drawer!

Comment: where to put above line ?

Comment: @KhushbooVerghese see my answer and tell if it makes sense! its not about putting lines! its about foreseeing the architecture of the application!

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE PLEASE USE!!!** ADD FRAGMENT INSTEAD OF REPLACE FRAGMENT AS **YOLO** said in the answer
you can get the stack count and use it in the favour of your algorithm

Well I don't that this is the best way to do the thing that you like! but still it can help you . in your mainActivity where your bottom navigation is ! have that global declared and initialised ! and do something like this in onResume method ! 
you can empty or check the stack of fragments using  !

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

do something like this in your onResume! pass out desired item number(#position) in the getItem of bottom navigation!

```
@Override
 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
  // here you can check the stack that last fragment in stack is the one that
  //opened the 2nd activity then you can use its fragment to be loaded in  
  //transaction and also highlight the the bottomnav's tab
    bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with following:

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
                transaction.replace(R.id.home_container, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(fragmentName)
                transaction.commit();
```