# Why can't I use an intent to transition back to a previous fragment in my Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, fragment

I make a transition from a fragment to an activity but I am unable to transition back to the fragment without my app crashing.

Here is my fragment code:

```
package com.riverstonetech.gositeuk.ui.scotland

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.riverstonetech.gositeuk.CountriesActivity
import com.riverstonetech.gositeuk.R
import com.riverstonetech.gositeuk.RegionActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_scotland.*

class ScotlandFragment : Fragment() {

    // Access a Cloud Firestore instance
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    lateinit var adapter : ArrayAdapter<String>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scotland, container, false)

        (requireActivity() as CountriesActivity).initializeCustomActionBar(R.drawable.scotland_flag, R.string.title_regions)

        var regions : ArrayList<String>

        val docRef = db.collection("UKSites").document("Scotland")

        val progressBar: ProgressBar = root.findViewById(R.id.regionsLoadingProgressBar)

        docRef.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->

                progressBar?.visibility = ProgressBar.VISIBLE

                if (document != null) {

                    regions = document.get("Regions") as ArrayList<String>

                    adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.list_item, regions)

                    regionsListView.adapter = adapter

                    regionsListView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->

                        val intent = Intent(activity!!, RegionActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("SUB_COUNTRY", regions[position])
                        startActivity(intent)


                    }

                    progressBar?.visibility = ProgressBar.GONE

                } else {
                    Log.d("Debug", "No such document")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.d("Debug", "get failed with ", exception)
            }

        return root
    }
}
```

And here is the relevant code in my activity class `RegionActivity`:

```
    fun previousSubCountryListButtonClicked(view: View) {

        val intent: Intent = Intent(this, ScotlandFragment::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
```

Here is the error output in the logcat window:

```
2020-02-10 15:46:54.089 27008-27008/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.riverstonetech.gositeuk, PID: 27008
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
```

I don't have enough knowledge of fragments and activity to work out why this doesn't work so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Intents are for activities; you need a fragment manager doing a fragment transaction to load your fragment https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Adding

Comment: what are you doing? Navigation or what? are you navigating to previous fragment? BTW activity and fragment lifecycle are necessary to learn before playing with them here is a cool tip, make a new project and from where you select blank activity there will be bottom navigation activity then apply, ok, finish, there you can find cool features about fragment navigation and little bit MVVM, if you still wanna do it from scratch you have to do something called fragment transaction as it mention in above comment.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Can you help me out a little with some code? Thanks

Comment: If you want to go from your RegionActivity back to ScotlandFragment you can use the intent you mentioned but instead of ScotlandFragment::class, add the name of the activity that hosts that fragment. How do you load ScotlandFragment in the first place?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I have tried using name of activity that hosts activity but it doesn't take me to correct previous fragment, there are 4 fragments in the activity. I'm not sure how the ScotlandFragment is loaded in the first place as I have used the bottom navigation activity template when I first started the project. May this XML is how it is loaded: ```    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_scotland"
        android:name="com.riverstonetech.gositeuk.ui.scotland.ScotlandFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_scotland"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_scotland" />```

Comment: See if this could be of any help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51535870/back-button-behaviour-on-activity-to-fragment-in-bottom-navigation-view

Comment: @NikosHidalgo, thanks but that doesn't really help. There too much code there in Java to understand what is going on.

Comment: Find the bottomnavigation activity and locate its Fragment Manager. See the FragmentTransactions that it does and every time a new fragment is loaded add it to backstack using something like _transaction.addToBackStack(fragment_name)_

Comment: There is no instantiation of FragmentManager anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You are making this way more complicated than it needs to be.

To return from `RegionActivity` to the previous `Activity/Fragment`, you just need to call `finish()`. That will destroy `RegionActivity` and return to whatever `Activity` was underneath it, in the same state it was in when you launched `RegionActivity`.

Comment: Thanks but if I switch to another activity before I try to switch back to the previous fragment I get a previous activity instead of the fragment.

Comment: Sorry but that makes no sense. A `Fragment` is hosted by an `Activity`. There is always an `Activity` involved. You should probably post more of your code so we can help.

Comment: Did you actually replace the code you have in `previousSubCountryListButtonClicked()` with a call to `finish()`?

Answer (score 0):

I used `finish()` instead of trying to switch to the fragment using intents.